# Does a debugger interpret code or just runs it?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, stack, symbol-table

Say I put a breakpoint somewhere in the code. Would the debugger just let the program run towards that point or it actually interprets it, instruction by instruction? Assume the program is compiled using the -g flag. I am asking, because my friend was saying that the debugger is unable to keep addresses of variables in the stack in the symbol table, and therefore needs to interpret. However, I argued that at least the debugger knows the offset of those stack variables from the start of the stack when a function is entered.

Comment: It runs the code, and knows the offsets of variables in the stack given the current stack pointer. It used to support breakpoints by overwriting the opcode to break on with an `INT 3` instruction on x86, which is trap to debugger. I'm not 100% sure of the mechanism on x86_64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say I put a breakpoint somewhere in the code. Would the debugger just let the program run towards that point or it actually interprets it, instruction by instruction?

It depends! If your system has hardware breakpoints simply the address to break is written in a hardware register. If the cpu program counter reaches one of the trap addresses the cpu generate some kind of trap/irq/... which stop the program and calls some function of the debugger.

If your system has writable memory but no hardware breakpoints often the code at the breakpoint will be replaced with some kind of trap instruction which executes some functions in the debugger.

If your execution memory could not be written and there is no hardware breakpoint available it is sometimes possible to run the code in single step mode. After each assembler step the debugger is called back. The debugger itself holds the list of breakpoints.

> Assume the program is compiled using the -g flag. I am asking, because my friend was saying that the debugger is unable to keep addresses of variables in the stack in the symbol table, and therefore needs to interpret

This is quite wrong. The debug information contains also the format of each stack frame. Which information/variable/content is placed on which *realtiv* position in the stack depends on the context of the actual running stackframe. The debug information contains all needed information's for this! If you stop your program the debugger knows the address and can calculate the actual context/block of the program. And the debug information *knows* which stack frame content is actual used at this frame.

> However, I argued that at least the debugger knows the offset of those stack variables from the start of the stack when a function is entered.

Right!

The debugger itself did not "run" or "simulate" a program. The debugger itself only controls how a program is executed on the given system. The system can also be a simulator which simulates the cpu and target system. Also remote debugging is a topic in this context. On every kind of system is a need for a debug interface to the system itself.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, GDB "virtualizes" the environment. Take reverse execution, for example: There is simply no way you can "reverse" the real CPU. What GDB does is keeping track of the process, pause execution at the furthest point, and provide you with a "view" of a previous state of the environment until you return to the actual state.

Also, GDB can *cross*-debug, i.e. with GDB running on your system and the debugged executable running on a connected embedded system. In this case, GDB isn't even running on the same CPU architecture... but it isn't "interpreting" the executable (it still needs the other system to actually do the execution); it's *instrumenting* it, i.e. keeping track of things and allowing you to pause and inspect its execution.

What `-g` does is adding debug symbols. In release code, your variable `foo` is no longer `foo`, but merely an address in memory. *With* debugging symbols, GDB can still tell that address `0xdeadbeef` is, indeed, `foo`. Seeing function names in a stack trace is so much more enlightening than a list of addresses, too...

(Disclaimer: I am far from a GDB grok. While I am using it every day, my useage is the bread-and-butter variety. I am sure others will show up with *much* more detailed answers, or even point out where I am wrong, but until then, this is the best answer *I* can give. ;-) )